# How to fix lighthouse errors in Vite 3?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, vite

Using Vite 3 with vue/typescript/vuetify, I am running lighthouse on Chrome dev tools, and I get these errors. The vite preview html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#6E2D91">
    <meta name="description" content="Sample Web App">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.79acedba.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.4a576584.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The original html file was

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#6E2D91">
    <meta name="description" content="Sample Web App">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

How can I fix these?

Comment: click on `Learn more` for googles so-called *advice*

Comment: I did, but nothing useful there because this is vite specific. I tried putting async and defer, but no difference. I think it has something to do with the css link tags, but vite puts it on the top.

Comment: I also need this answer